# Close all firefox tabs with BATCH

Tags: batch-file, tasklist, taskkill

I try to close all firefox if there are more than one. I want to do loop that check the firefox process and close and check again until there is no any firefox process.

This is my code:

```
:loop
taskkill /im "firefox.exe"
tasklist /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" goto loop
```

Where is my wrong in this command ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:loop 
tasklist /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" | find "firefox.exe" >nul && ( taskkill /im firefox.exe >nul & goto loop )
```

Get list of tasks, and if `firefox.exe` included in it, then kill it and goto loop

Comment: And am wondering how to open it again using batch. Mostly like a restart batch command ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following to force kill FF windows:

```
taskkill /F /FI "ImageName eq firefox.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

One `taskkill` command will kill every firefox process - unless it is not responding.

You could use `two taskkill` commands separated by a `delay` of several seconds, and the second one should use the `/f` force switch.

Comment: I am using windows xp and taskkill doesn't kill every firefox process.
If there are 2 windows for firefox it kills only one window. In the task manager it seems only one process but I don't understand why it does'nt working. Also the answer of @MC works really fine

Comment: `start notepad.exe & start notepad.exe & taskkill /im notepad.exe` <-- try that command.  Only if a process is not responding will it remain in memory, and my answer describes how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

I do

```
@echo off

TASKKILL /IM firefox.exe /F

pause>nul

exit
```

I'm on windows 7, it works for me